# Show a number of items on clicking show more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am showing travel packages from database in loop on a page, where more than 40-50 packages getting shown.

i want only four packages to be shown at start and when i click on show more button it should show 4 more packages and so on.

```
    <?php foreach($blogrand as $blogsrand){ ?>
    <div class="grid-item-wrap large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns group-0">
        <div class="shadow grid-item rel bdg1">
            <div class="img"><a href="<?=base_url();?>tours/<?php echo $blogsrand['tourslug'];?>"><img alt="<?php echo $blogsrand['tourname'];?>" class="mmtTI hide" src="<?php echo $blogsrand['banner'];?>" /><img alt="<?php echo $blogsrand['tourname'];?>" class="mmtTIM" src="<?php echo $blogsrand['banner'];?>" />

                </a></div>

            <div class="content eq-7" style="height:110px">
                <h3><a href="<?=base_url();?>tours/<?php echo $blogsrand['tourslug'];?>"><?php echo $blogsrand['tourname'];?></a></h3>
                <div style="background-color: transparent;width:100%;display: inline-block;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom: 1px;font-size: 12px; color:#ff9016;" class="bld lsp upc drk" data-popup="range-reveal-1">Trip Type : <?php echo $blogsrand['tourtype'];?><br><span style="text-transform:capitalize; color:black;">Trip Duration : <?php echo $blogsrand['hotels'];?></span><br><span style="text-transform:capitalize; color:#959595;">Places Covered : <?php echo $blogsrand['tourplaces'];?></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

<div class="cnt"><a class="bld f19 wht wrBCol3 colLinkPad viewMoreTrigger5">Show More</a></div>
```

how to achieve this by CSS or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet to get you started. Try it out, play around with it, try to adopt it to your use case, and when you encounter specific issues you're unable to debug and figure out yourself, then feel free to ask on stackoverflow. Be sure to include minimum reproducing examples when applicable.

```js
let data = [...Array(50)].map((_, i) => ({i, r: Math.random()}));

document.querySelector('#more-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let showing = document.querySelector('#container').childElementCount;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    let d = data[showing + i];
    row.textContent = `${d.i}, ${d.r}`;
    document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(row);
  }  
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="more-button">more</button>
```

Comment: thanks, i have solved it. is it required to post the solution or should i leave it as it is?